# Joomla databases and how to extract the data

Tags: php, mysql

i have kind of hacked away at a joomla component, it works well with one table, but i was looking at having more than one table, but i cant seem to get it to draw from 2 tables. ie one table will have lets say article information, the other table will have other data relevant to the articles and their id's. Any ideas on how i can do this

Comment: You use the Joomla's `JDatabase` API to access the database. [Read the docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Selecting Records from Multiple Tables**

Using the JDatabaseQuery's join methods, you can select records from multiple related tables. The generic "join" method takes two arguments; the join "type" (inner, outer, left, right) and the join condition. In the following example you will notice that we can use all of the keywords we would normally use if we were writing a native SQL query, including the AS keyword for aliasing tables and the ON keyword for creating relationships between tables. Also note that the table alias is used in all methods which reference table columns (I.e. select, where, order).

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all articles for users who have a username which starts with 'a'.
// Order it by the created date.
// Note by putting 'a' as a second parameter will generate `#__content` AS `a`
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('a.*', 'b.username', 'b.name')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
    ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__users', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.created_by') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.id') . ')')
    ->where($db->quoteName('b.username') . ' LIKE \'a%\'')
    ->order($db->quoteName('a.created') . ' DESC');

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Even if you create your components using [Component Creator](http://www.component-creator.com) you still have to do this kind of stuff manually.